# Question about using particle 에 with Korean adverb 이제?

Tags: particle, adverbs

So I'm using the website, 'howtostudyKorean' and I have a question about a sentence I recently encountered. Here's the sentence. 저는 이제 수업을 시작할 거예요. Now this sentence is supposed to say, according to the website, "I will start the class now". Here's my question. Why isn't particle 에 attached to 이제?

이제 is an adverb indicating *when* and according to this website, adverbs indicating *when* and *where* should have the particle 에 attached. So can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or just help me with the rules of Korean adverbs?

Comment: "adverbs indicating when and where should have the particle 에 attached" - could you link to exactly where you read that?

Comment: 에 is attached to 체언 (including nouns) not to adverbs.

Answer (score 1):

-에 is a particle that makes a word adverb. It can only come right after a substantive word to make its form adverbial, not after an adverb word itself. 이제 is already an adverb, so there is no need to attach -에 after it.

The usage of -에 is similar to the one of 'at' in English. 'at' can come in front of nouns, not adverbs.